# Mod_rewrite and Cakephp

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-1.3

I have tried various methods to try and get this working correctly (I am not by any chance knowledgable about mod_rewriting) but to no avail.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

I am after trying several different configuration attempt still coming up with blank screens...

The current config is below:

cake folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

cake/app folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

cake/app/webroot folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 180.180.180.180:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cake
     ServerName something.something.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
<Directory "/var/www/html/membersarea">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Once again, any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rewrite rules were incorrect [syntax etc] you should be getting a server 500 error. Turn back on your logging - make sure php is dumping errors & you should see why you are getting a blank screen.

in an php file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

in an .htaccess

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Comment: You are a legend - thanks for this, exactly what I needed to sort it out!

Comment: you should also point your document root the webroot folder of your app! then those other rewrite files are unnecessary.